# Map multiple WTForm fields to one attribute using Flask-WTForm

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a form that maps correctly to my model. What I want to do is have users input their date of birth using three `SelectField` (day, month, year) and write the combination of those three values to my `model.dateOfBirth`. I know of the existing `DateField` and `DateTimeField` options, but neither of them are suitable.

I've attempted this using a `FormField` but it fails when I call `populate_obj` on the whole Form `'str' object has no attribute 'day'`, assuming that it is trying to set `model.dateOfBirth.day` which of course, doesn't exist.

I can pull all the relevant data from `form.data` and write to model outside of `populate_obj`, but I can't seem to remove the `dateOfBirth` data to stop `populate_obj` from failing. There are of course other questions about how I could prefill the form data when passing `obj` on form creation, but I'm willing to sacrifice that for now.

I've looked at using a `FieldList`, but the docs say that it gives all its data back in a list, instead of a dict, which will still give me the same issues

## Forms

```
class DOBForm(Form):

    day = SelectField(u'Please enter your date of birth',
        choices=days,
        validators=[InputRequired(message=u' ')]
    )

    month = SelectField(u' ',
        choices=months,
        validators=[InputRequired(message=u' ')]
    )

    year = SelectField(u' ',
        choices=years,
        validators=[InputRequired(message=u' ')]
    )
```

and

```
class MainForm(Form):

    dateOfBirth = FormField(DOBForm)
```

## Model

```
class Model

    dateOfBirth = db.Column('dateOfBirth', Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function for this.

```
from datetime import datetime
def date_of_birth(**kwargs):
    day = kwargs['day']
    month = kwargs['month']
    year = kwargs['year']
    strip="-"
    seq = (day,month,year)
    date = datetime.strptime(strip.join(seq) , '%d-%m-%Y')
    birthday = stringDate.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    dob = Model()
    dob.dateOfBirth = birthday
    session = Session()
    session.add(dob)
    session.commit()
    retval = row2dict(dob)
    session.close()
    return retval
```

Now you can call this function.
I don't test this function yet. If you get any error or have any query , let me know..